# How does expo publish overwrite my Testflight download?

Tags: react-native, app-store-connect, expo, react-native-ios, testflight

I have a react-native application which is using Expo. When I want a build on my iOS device, I run

expo build:ios

then I upload the build to my appstoreconnect account and manage the build version through Testflight. Then on my iOS device I'm able to download it.

This all makes sense, as it mirrors the android process of building, creating a downloadable link, and having the end user download the latest link. But if I make a change and run "expo publish"... the app downloaded on my iOS device automatically has the changes that I made to the source code. How is that possible? Why don't I need to rebuild and reupload the .ipa to Apple for them to distribute through Testflight?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because of the Expo "OTA" updates system (over the air).

When you publish to a release channel, users will automatically get the new update.

If you make some changes in app.json, or if you updated some native codes, you will need to re-build your app. The OTA updates only works for JS updates.

Comment: Thank you! So does this mean in theory for an expo app a user would never have to go back to the App Store and “update”? Since the developer can just push all updates using the OTA system?

Comment: Exactly ! But it only works for javascript updates. If you add a library which requires native code, you will need publish a new build.

Comment: That makes sense! What about static assets? If I updated an image would that file get pushed via release channel or does that constitute a new build?

Comment: It will handle it for you. If the image is used somewhere (by using a require), Expo will detect it and push it into your new update.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much this really helps!

Comment: You can read more about this here: https://docs.expo.io/guides/configuring-ota-updates/